# NameError: name 'sheet' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I got an error:

> NameError: name 'sheet' is not defined .I wanna parse excel and print the content.

My wrote codes:

```
class ReadData():
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
        self.companies = []

    def read(self):
        for row_index in range(2, sheet.nrows):
            rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)
            print(rows)

x = ReadData('./data/excel1.xlsx')
x.read()
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.Should I add something to use **init** ?How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `self.sheet` instead of just `sheet`. So update your method as

```
def read(self):
    # ------------------------v
    for row_index in range(2, self.sheet.nrows):
       #---------v
        rows = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
        print(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

in read function, there is no sheet defined. you should use `self.sheet.nrows`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ReadData():
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
        self.companies = []

    def read(self):
        for row_index in range(2, self.sheet.nrows):
            rows = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
            print(rows)

x = ReadData('./data/excel1.xlsx')
x.read()
```

I added a `self.` ahead of `sheet` at line 8

Comment: You have missed `self` at one more place in the `range`

Comment: Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says that it can not find an attribute `sheet` in your `read()` method. You have used `sheet` at two places:
1: In `for` loop's `range` 
2: In the first line of `for` loop.

If you want to use any attribute inside any method in `python`, then it can be only a class variable or a local variable or an instance variable or some imported attribute.

`class variable` or `instance variable` can be accessed via `self`.

In your case, `sheet` is an `instance variable` and hence it can be only accessed using `self`.

So if you change those two occurrences of `sheet` by `self.sheet`, it would work.

Here is your corrected code

```
class ReadData(object):
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
        self.companies = []

    def read(self):
        for row_index in range(2, self.sheet.nrows):
            rows = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
            print(rows)

x = ReadData('./data/excel1.xlsx')
x.read()
```